# loop though results from information schema mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to find all the tables that has a column name called RecordID and then loop over those tables to see if the RecordID > 5000 or not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE check_IDs ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE result varchar(50);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR for SELECT table_name FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE column_name = 'RecordID' ;   

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
     FETCH cur1 INTO result;
     IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
     END IF;

      Select * from `result` where RecordID > 5000;
    END LOOP;
    close cur1;    
END;
```

it says table result not found.

Answer (score 0):

It's got to be

```
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', result, '`WHERE RecordID > 5000;)';
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

instead of

```
Select * from `result` where RecordID > 5000;
```

see the examples (last one) of [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Your statement will use the hardcoded table name `result`. It seems, there's no such table in your database.